# How to check if a string is part of a DataFrame Column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple dataframe with 99 columns which I would like to make a query that finds the counties that belong to regions 1 or 2, whose name starts with 'Washington', and whose POPESTIMATE2015 was greater than their POPESTIMATE 2014:

```
census_df = pd.read_csv('census.csv')

print(census_df[(census_df.REGION == 1) | (census_df.REGION == 2) \
   & (census_df.POPESTIMATE2015 > census_df.POPESTIMATE2014) \
   & (census_df.CTYNAME.isin(['Washington']))][['STNAME', 'CTYNAME']])
```

I tried different ways and filter for "Washington" is not working at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.str.startswith`. Also, use `loc` access is a better practice than chained indexing:

```
census_df.loc[
    census_df.REGION.isin([1,2]) &
    census_df.POPESTIMATE2015.gt(census_df.POPESTIMATE2014) &
    census_df.CTYNAME.str.startswith('Washington'),
    ['STNAME','CTYNAME']
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your filter does not work because you are using `isin`, which is checking whether specified values are contained in the Series. So, you are basically selecting only samples where CTYNAME = 'Washington'. Consider a toy example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'REGION': [1, 2, 3, 1, 4], 'POPESTIMATE2015': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5], 'POPESTIMATE2014': [4, 3, 3, 8, 5],
   'CTYNAME': ['Washington', 'Washington_PD', 'AD_Washington', 'Washington Something', 'Different'],
   'STNAME': ['ST1', 'ST2', 'ST3', 'ST4', 'ST5']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

With `isin` you will only select:

```
df.loc[
df.REGION.isin([1,2]) &
df.POPESTIMATE2015.gt(df.POPESTIMATE2014) &
df.CTYNAME.isin(['Washington']),
['STNAME','CTYNAME']]


0   ST1 Washington
```

Instead, if you want to select samples where `CTYNAME` starts with "Washington" you should use `df.CTYNAME.str.startswith`:

```
df.loc[
df.REGION.isin([1,2]) &
df.POPESTIMATE2015.gt(df.POPESTIMATE2014) &
df.CTYNAME.str.startswith('Washington'),
['STNAME','CTYNAME']]
```

Obtaining:

```
0   ST1 Washington
1   ST2 Washington_PD
```

You can also use `df.CTYNAME.str.contains` to select all the samples where CTYNAME contains a word "Washington"